# how implement JAX-WS, into a JAVA-EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-ws

I'm new on JAVA-EE
My project actually have the next structure:

> - ear
> - ejb
> - jpa
> - rest
> - web

I have to consume a web service from a partner, but it is on SOAP, and I actualy only have REST service

I found the best way to do it, it's creatig a JAX-WS, for hadling SOAP

How can I add a JAX-WS to my structure project?, or do you have a better SOAP implementing solution for this case.
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have to consume a SOAP web service.

So the first step would generate the client code from the WSDL. I assume that you are calling the web service from an EJB so the client code goes to the EJB project.

Comment: so, is it not necessary using JAX-WS?

Comment: The name of the tool is wsimport. This will generate the client from the WSDL file https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/wsimport.htm